# Odoo Change Calendar View in Project for Task

Tags: calendar, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I'am install Odoo 8.

I want create and see task in Calendar View with time not only date.

For example:

***what do I have?***

[image: http://imgur.com/3t0WJjp]

***what do I want?***

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rpRnVVh.jpg]

I can't change time in calendar view for tasks in project. Tasks use "all day" not time.

I try change project_view.xml in addons.

I change `date_start=dedline` to

```
<calendar color="user_id" date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_end" string="Tasks"> <field name="name"/> <field name="project_id"/> </calendar>
```

I use value from gant view(date_start and date_stop)
[image]
but it doesn't work. Please help. Thank you for your help.